# BlackJack Algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, blackjack

What is the general alogirthm for a BlackJack game ?
I'm writing one in c++ and end up having WAY too many if statements which ruin the whole thing.

The project is a win32 GUI application, and Im posting the message loop as well as the part of the program that checks the game's status
Posting the complete code will make it humongous, so here are the links to all the files:
[Full Source Code](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/35856163/Code.zip)

### Message Loop

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc( HWND hWnd, UINT Msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam ){
  switch(Msg)
  {
  case WM_PAINT:
  {
      PAINTSTRUCT PS;
      HDC hDC = BeginPaint(hWnd, &PS);
      You.Draw(hDC);
      Dealer.Draw(hDC);
      EndPaint(hWnd, &PS);
      if(Bet.Enabled){
          Bet.GetFocus();
          Bet.Select(0,Bet.Length());
      }
  }
  return 0;
  case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC:
  {
      SetBkMode((HDC)wParam, TRANSPARENT);
  }
  return (INT_PTR)(HBRUSH)GetStockObject(NULL_BRUSH);
  case WM_CREATE:
  {
      //Create edit control
      Bet.Create(hWnd, 10, 550, 100, 25, "0");
      //Create labels
      char Buffer[30];
      sprintf(Buffer, "%d", You.HandValue());
      BetLabel.Create(hWnd, 10, 500, 100, 40, "Enter Bet Amount");
      GameControls.Create(hWnd, 10, 375, 100, 40, "Game Controls");
      PlayerLabels.Create(hWnd, 10, 10, 100, 20, "You:");
      PlayerLabels.Create(hWnd, 10, 150, 100, 20, "Dealer:");
      HandValueLabel.Create(hWnd, (int)You.x[You.cards] + 85, (int)You.y[You.cards] + 25, 100, 20, Buffer);
      YourMoney.Create(hWnd, 125, 500, 100, 40, "Your money: ");
      sprintf(Buffer, "%d", You.money);
      MoneyValue.Create(hWnd, 125, 525, 100, 40, Buffer);
      //Create buttons
      Ok.Create(hWnd, 10, 600, 100, 50, "Ok");
      Hit.Create(hWnd, 10, 425, 100, 50, "Hit");
      Stand.Create(hWnd, 120, 425, 100, 50, "Stand");
      //Select Text
      Bet.Select(0,3);
  }
  return 0;
  case WM_CLOSE:
    exit(0);
    break;
  case WM_COMMAND:
  {
      switch(HIWORD(wParam))
      {
      case BN_CLICKED:
      {
          switch(LOWORD(wParam))
          {
          case ID_OK:
          {
              //Place bet
              int bet = 0;
              bet = StringToNumber(Bet.Text());
              You.money -= bet;
              char Buffer[30];
              sprintf(Buffer, "%d", You.money);
              MoneyValue.SetText(Buffer);
              //Update the window
              InvalidateRect(hWnd, 0, TRUE);
              You.Bet = YES;
              Ok.Disable();
              Bet.Disable();
              You.DealCard();
              You.DealCard();
              Dealer.DealCard();
              Dealer.DealCard();
              You.win = false;
              You.bust = false;
              You.playing = YES;
              Dealer.win = NO;
              Dealer.bust = NO;
              Dealer.playing = YES;
          }
          break;
          case ID_HIT:
          {
             if(You.HandValue() < 21 && You.playing && !You.bust){
                 //Deal a card to the player, if he hasn't won or lost
                 You.DealCard();
             }
             if((Dealer.HandValue() <= 17 || Dealer.HandValue() < You.HandValue()) && Dealer.playing)
                       {
                         Dealer.DealCard();
                       }
            //Update Hand Value
            char Buffer[30];
            sprintf(Buffer, "%d", You.HandValue());
            HandValueLabel.SetText(Buffer);
            InvalidateRect(hWnd,0,TRUE);
            MoveWindow(HandValueLabel.Handle, (int)You.x[You.cards] + 80, (int)You.y[You.cards] + 25, 100, 20, TRUE);
            RedrawWindow(hWnd, NULL, NULL, RDW_INVALIDATE | RDW_INTERNALPAINT);
          }
          break;
          case ID_STAND:
              if(Hit.Enabled){
                  //Don't deal more cards
                  Hit.Disable();
                  You.playing = false;
              }
              if((Dealer.HandValue() <= 17 || Dealer.HandValue() < You.HandValue()) && Dealer.playing){
                  //Deal a card to the dealer
                  Dealer.DealCard();
              }
          }
```

### StatusChecker

```
void ProcessStatus(HWND hWnd){
     if(Dealer.HandValue() > 17){
          if(Dealer.HandValue() > You.HandValue() && Dealer.playing){
              Dealer.playing = false;
            }
          else if(!You.playing && Dealer.HandValue() <= You.HandValue() && Dealer.playing){
              Dealer.DealCard();
            }
        }
      else if(Dealer.HandValue() <= 17 && Dealer.HandValue() <= You.HandValue() && !You.playing && Dealer.playing){
          Dealer.DealCard();
        }
      if(EvaluateStatus() != 0){
          status = OVER;
        }
     if(EvaluateStatus() == -1){
         switch(MessageBoxA(hWnd, "You Lost! \n Keep Playing ?", "You Lost!", MB_YESNO | MB_ICONQUESTION))
         {
         case IDYES:
             Reset();
             break;
         case IDNO:
             exit(0);
             break;
         }
     }
     else if(EvaluateStatus() == 1){
         switch(MessageBoxA(hWnd, "You Won! \n Keep Playing ?", "You Won!", MB_YESNO | MB_ICONQUESTION))
         {
         case IDYES:
             Reset();
             break;
         case IDNO:
             exit(0);
             break;
         }
     }
    }
int EvaluateStatus()
{
  if(You.HandValue() > 21 && You.playing)
    {
      You.bust = true;
      Dealer.win = true;
      You.playing = NO;
      return -1;
    }
  if(You.HandValue() == 21)
    {
      You.win = true;
      return 1;
    }
  if(Dealer.HandValue() > 21)
    {
      Dealer.bust = true;
      You.win = true;
      return 1;
    }
  if(Dealer.HandValue() == 21)
    {
      Dealer.win = true;
      return -1;
    }
  if(!You.playing && Dealer.HandValue() > You.HandValue() &&!Dealer.bust)
    {
      Dealer.win = true;
      return -1;
    }
  if(You.HandValue() > Dealer.HandValue() && (!You.playing && (!Dealer.playing || Dealer.bust)))
    {
      You.win = true;
      return 1;
    }
  if(You.HandValue() == Dealer.HandValue() && (!You.playing || !Dealer.playing))
    {
      You.win = true;
      return 1;
    }
```

Comment: Doesn't look that bad to me. When the game has a lot of rules, you'll get a lot of ifs. (Note: Not in every game though. If you can write the rules as a state machine, you can use two 2d arrays of states and function pointers indexed by state/action. First one showing "next" state, second one the function needed to be executed when that path is taken. Then all you need is a lot of small functions with similar prototypes and fill in the tables. I don't think this applies to blackjack though)

Comment: Also, it turns out that I was making the routine overly complex. Rather than asking the dealer and the player to be dealt one card each, the player should first hit, and then it is the dealers turn,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a first step: I probably wouldn't mix game logic and your GUI logic.. separate them into different modules.

And if you only have two players, you only need a bool to decide which one won. You don't need for both of the players Bust and Won variables.

Comment: I've been told so many time's before not to mix the two. But changes in GUI are what trigger the game. So how do I make It work?

Comment: You could set up an event like system, where the events raised in your GUI propagate to your logic classes.

Comment: put your game logic inside a class, for example. Then call the appropriate method of this class. Or you could go for a MVC design. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller

Comment: I had written out some stuff but I think a full answer is too long and this might be best off as a new question. The simplest answer though is to have a model that controls the game logic and then a GUI whose job is to display things and accept the user input and pass it on to the model. If in doubt where things should lie consider a hypothetical text only version alongside your GUI. If code is needed for both its probably in the model. If its only needed for one of GUI or text then it should be in just that one.

Comment: Ive already written a console version of blackjack. It worked, but it was filoled with disgusting global variables;

Answer (score 1):

A google search revealed [this PDF paper](http://www.bjmath.com/bjmath/heath/dheath.pdf) on BlackJack algorithms. I'm sure if you did some more research using Google, you could find things too.

To figure out how to work out the actual steps needing to be done to play the game, work out on paper the different steps of the game, then decide how you can create classes that represent parts of the game and functions in these classes to execute the different steps of the game.'

This could be an iterative thing, where you go through it, then create some classes, functions, etc, now you can go back and see if what you've done makes sense, improve on the design etc.

Perhaps also play the game and see what is done, how that could be translated into code.

Comment: Those are strategies and algorithm's on how to play black jack, as in, how to win.
What I wanted was the algorithm which DESCRIBES how the game proceeds.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the way the program handles messages, and am posting it as a seperate answer.
It is still broken because of a minor hiccup, but i think the general idea is solid. comments would be appreciated

### cards.h

```
/*
 * cards.h
 *
 *  Created on: Aug 31, 2011
 *      Author: Viraj
 */
#ifndef CARDS_H_
#define CARDS_H_
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#define STARTED true
#define OVER false
#define YES true
#define NO false
using namespace std;
HINSTANCE hApplication;
HBITMAP Bitmap;
char Buffer[30];
class Deck{
public:
    int deck[53];
    Deck(){
        for(int suit = 1; suit <= 4; suit++){
            for(int card = 1; card <= 13; card++){
                deck[((suit-1)*13)+card] = card;
            }
        }
        deck[0] = 0;
    }
};
Deck deck;
class Cards{
private:
    int card_seed;
    int suit_seed;
public:
    int card[11];
    int cards;
    int value[11];
    Cards(){
        fill(card, card + 10, 0);
        fill(value, value + 10, 0);
        cards = 0;
    }
    void DealCard()
    {
        cards++;
        while(!deck.deck[card[cards]]){
            card_seed = rand()%13 + 1;
            suit_seed = rand()%4 + 1;
            card[cards] = (suit_seed - 1)*13 + card_seed;
        }
        deck.deck[card[cards]] = 0;
        if(card_seed > 1 && card_seed < 11){
             value[cards] = card_seed;
        }
        else if(card_seed >= 11 && card_seed <= 13){
            value[cards] = 10;
        }
        else if(card_seed == 1){
            value[cards] = 11;
        }
    }
};
class Player : public Cards {
public:
    float x[11];
    float y[11];
    bool playing;
    bool bust;
    bool win;
    int money;
    Player(const char* Type){
        srand(time(NULL));
        playing = true;
        if(Type == "Dealer"){
            for(int card = 1; card <= 10; card++){
                x[card] = 10 + (card-1)*75;
                y[card] = 200;
            }
        }
        else{
            for(int card = 1; card <= 10; card++){
                x[card] = 10 + (card-1)*75;
                y[card] = 35;
                money = 1000;
            }
        }
    }
    void Reset(){
        cards = 0;
        fill(card, card + 10, 0);
        fill(value, value + 10, 0);
        playing = true;
    }
    int HandValue(){
        int sum = 0;
        for(int current_card = 1; current_card <= cards; current_card++){
            sum += value[current_card];
          }
        if(sum > 21){
            for(int current_card = 1; current_card <= cards; current_card++){
                if(value[current_card] == 11 && sum > 21){
                    value[current_card] = 1;
                    sum = HandValue();
                    break;
                  }
              }
          }
        return sum;
    }
    void Draw(HDC hDC){
        HDC MemoryDevice;
        for(int CardToLoad = 1; CardToLoad <= cards; CardToLoad++){
            Bitmap = LoadBitmap(hApplication, MAKEINTRESOURCE(card[CardToLoad]));
            MemoryDevice = CreateCompatibleDC(hDC);
            SelectObject(MemoryDevice, Bitmap);
            BitBlt(hDC, (int)x[CardToLoad], (int)y[CardToLoad], 75, 100, MemoryDevice, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
        }
        DeleteDC(MemoryDevice);
    }
};
class CONTROL{
public:
    HWND Handle;
    char* ClassName;
    char* Caption;
    DWORD ClassStyle;
    DWORD ExtendedStyle;
    int x;
    int y;
    int Width;
    int Height;
    int ID;
    bool Enabled;
    void Create(HWND ParentHandle, int x, int y, int Width, int Height, char* Caption){
        Handle = CreateWindowExA(ExtendedStyle, ClassName, Caption, ClassStyle, x, y, Width, Height, ParentHandle, (HMENU)ID, NULL, NULL);
        Enabled = true;
        CONTROL::Caption = Caption;
        CONTROL::x = x;
        CONTROL::y = y;
        CONTROL::Width = Width;
        CONTROL::Height = Height;
    }
    void GetFocus(){
        SetFocus(Handle);
    }
    void Disable(){
        EnableWindow(Handle, FALSE);
        Enabled = false;
    }
    void Enable(){
        EnableWindow(Handle, TRUE);
        Enabled = true;
    }
    void SetText(char* String){
        SetWindowTextA(Handle, String);
    }
};
class BUTTON : public CONTROL {
public:
    BUTTON(int Identifier){
        ClassStyle = BS_PUSHBUTTON | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD;
        ID = Identifier;
        ClassName = "BUTTON";
        ExtendedStyle = 0;
    }
};
class EDIT : public CONTROL {
public:
    EDIT(int Identifier){
        ClassStyle = ES_NUMBER | WS_VISIBLE | ES_CENTER | WS_CHILD | ES_NOHIDESEL;
        ExtendedStyle = WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE;
        ID = Identifier;
        ClassName = "EDIT";
    }
    void Select(int first, int last){
        Edit_SetSel(Handle, first, last);
    }
    int Length(){
        return Edit_GetTextLength(Handle);
    }
    const char* Text(){
        char Buffer[Length() + 1];
        Edit_GetText(Handle, (LPTSTR)&Buffer, Length() + 1);
        string String = Buffer;
        return String.c_str();
    }
};
class STATIC : public CONTROL {
public:
    STATIC() {
        ClassStyle = WS_VISIBLE | SS_CENTER | WS_CHILD;
        ID = 0;
        ClassName = "STATIC";
        ExtendedStyle = 0;
    }
};
Player You("You"), Dealer("Dealer");
BUTTON Ok(ID_OK), Hit(ID_HIT), Stand(ID_STAND);
EDIT Bet(ID_BET);
STATIC BetLabel, GameControls, PlayerLabels, HandValueLabel, YourMoney, MoneyValue, Bust;
class Game{
public:
    bool started;
    Game(){
        started = false;
    }
    void Stop(){
        started = false;
    }
    void ResetGame(HWND hWnd){
        //Reset Players
        You.Reset();
        Dealer.Reset();
        //Reset Controls
        Ok.Enable();
        Bet.Enable();
        Hit.Enable();
        //Reset Hand value
        sprintf(Buffer, "%d", You.HandValue());
        HandValueLabel.SetText(Buffer);
        //Reset deck
        deck = Deck();
        //Stop the game
        started = false;
        //Update the Display
        InvalidateRect(hWnd, 0, TRUE);
        RedrawWindow(hWnd, NULL, NULL, RDW_INVALIDATE | RDW_INTERNALPAINT);
    }
    int SendMessage(HWND hWnd, int ButtonID, unsigned int MESSAGE, int Information, char* _Information){
        return ProcessMessage(hWnd, ButtonID, MESSAGE, Information, _Information);
    }
    int ProcessMessage(HWND hWnd, int ButtonID, unsigned int MESSAGE, int Information, char* _Information){
        switch(MESSAGE)
        {
        case START_GAME:
            //Place Bet
            You.money -= Information;
            started = YES;
            sprintf(Buffer, "%d", You.money);
            //Update Controls
            MoneyValue.SetText(Buffer);
            Ok.Disable();
            Bet.Disable();
            //Deal two cards to player and dealer
            You.DealCard();
            You.DealCard();
            Dealer.DealCard();
            Dealer.DealCard();
            //Update the Hand Value Label
            sprintf(Buffer, "%d", You.HandValue());
            HandValueLabel.SetText(Buffer);
            //Move the label
            MoveWindow(HandValueLabel.Handle, (int)You.x[You.cards] + 80, (int)You.y[You.cards] + 25, 100, 20, TRUE);
            //Send PAINT message
            InvalidateRect(hWnd,0, TRUE);
            RedrawWindow(hWnd, NULL, NULL, RDW_INVALIDATE | RDW_INTERNALPAINT);
            //Check for BlackJacks
            if(You.HandValue() == 21){
                SendMessage(hWnd, 0, INTERNAL, YOU_WIN, "");
            }
            else if(Dealer.HandValue() == 21){
                SendMessage(hWnd, 0, INTERNAL, DEALER_WIN, "");
            }
            break;
        case STAND:
            if(started){
                Hit.Disable();
                You.playing = false;
            }
            break;
        case INTERNAL:
            switch(Information)
            {
            case DEALER_WIN:
                return MessageBoxA(hWnd, "You Loose! \n Play Again ?", "Game Over", MB_YESNO | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
            case YOU_WIN:
                return MessageBoxA(hWnd, "You Win! \n Keep Playing ?", "Game Over", MB_YESNO | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
            }
        break;
        case IDLE:
            if(started){
                //Check for BlackJacks
                if(Dealer.HandValue() == 21){
                    started = false;
                    switch(SendMessage(hWnd, 0, INTERNAL, DEALER_WIN, ""))
                    {
                    case IDYES:
                        ResetGame(hWnd);
                        return 0;
                    case IDNO:
                        exit(0);
                        return 0;
                    }
                }
                if(!You.playing && Dealer.playing && Dealer.HandValue() < You.HandValue())
                    Dealer.DealCard();
                    //Update the Window
                    InvalidateRect(hWnd,0, TRUE);
                    RedrawWindow(hWnd, NULL, NULL, RDW_INVALIDATE | RDW_INTERNALPAINT);
                    //Check for a Bust
                    if(Dealer.HandValue() > 21){
                        switch(SendMessage(hWnd, 0, INTERNAL, YOU_WIN, ""))
                        {
                        case IDYES:
                            ResetGame(hWnd);
                            return 0;
                        case IDNO:
                            exit(0);
                            return 0;
                        }
                    }
                    if(Dealer.HandValue() == 21){
                        switch(SendMessage(hWnd, 0, INTERNAL, YOU_WIN, ""))
                        {
                        case IDYES:
                            ResetGame(hWnd);
                            return 0;
                        case IDNO:
                            exit(0);
                            return 0;
                        }
                    }

                }
        break;
        case HIT:
            //Check to see who's still playing and deal a card to them
            if(started){
            if(You.playing){
                You.DealCard();
                //Update the Hand Value Label
                sprintf(Buffer, "%d", You.HandValue());
                HandValueLabel.SetText(Buffer);
                //Move the label and update the screen
                MoveWindow(HandValueLabel.Handle, (int)You.x[You.cards] + 80, (int)You.y[You.cards] + 25, 100, 20, TRUE);
                InvalidateRect(hWnd, 0, TRUE);
                RedrawWindow(hWnd, NULL, NULL, RDW_INVALIDATE | RDW_INTERNALPAINT);
                //Check for a BlackJack
                if(You.HandValue() == 21){
                    started = false;
                    switch(SendMessage(hWnd, 0, INTERNAL, YOU_WIN, ""))
                    {
                    case IDYES:
                        ResetGame(hWnd);
                        return 0;
                    case IDNO:
                        exit(0);
                        return 0;
                    }
                }
                //Check for a bust
                if(You.HandValue() > 21){
                    started = false;
                    switch(SendMessage(hWnd, 0, INTERNAL, YOU_WIN, ""))
                    {
                    case IDYES:
                        ResetGame(hWnd);
                        return 0;
                    case IDNO:
                        exit(0);
                        return 0;
                    }
                }
            }
            if(Dealer.playing){
                Dealer.DealCard();
                InvalidateRect(hWnd, 0, TRUE);
                RedrawWindow(hWnd, NULL, NULL, RDW_INVALIDATE | RDW_INTERNALPAINT);
                //Check for BlackJack
                if(Dealer.HandValue() == 21){
                    started = false;
                    switch(SendMessage(hWnd, 0, INTERNAL, DEALER_WIN, ""))
                    {
                    case IDYES:
                        ResetGame(hWnd);
                        return 0;
                    case IDNO:
                        exit(0);
                        return 0;
                    }
                }
                //Check for Bust
                if(Dealer.HandValue() > 21){
                    started = false;
                    switch(SendMessage(hWnd, 0, INTERNAL, YOU_WIN, ""))
                    {
                    case IDYES:
                        ResetGame(hWnd);
                        return 0;
                    case IDNO:
                        exit(0);
                        return 0;
                    }

                }
            }
            }
            break;
        }
        return 0;
    }
};
Game game;
#endif
```

---

### Message Loop

```
 switch(Msg)
  {
  case WM_PAINT:
  {
      PAINTSTRUCT PS;
      HDC hDC = BeginPaint(hWnd, &PS);
      You.Draw(hDC);
      Dealer.Draw(hDC);
      EndPaint(hWnd, &PS);
      if(Bet.Enabled){
          Bet.GetFocus();
          Bet.Select(0,Bet.Length());
      }
  }
  return 0;
  case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC:
  {
      SetBkMode((HDC)wParam, TRANSPARENT);
  }
  return (INT_PTR)(HBRUSH)GetStockObject(NULL_BRUSH);
  case WM_CREATE:
  {
      //Create edit control
      Bet.Create(hWnd, 10, 550, 100, 25, "0");
      //Create labels
      char Buffer[30];
      sprintf(Buffer, "%d", You.HandValue());
      BetLabel.Create(hWnd, 10, 500, 100, 40, "Enter Bet Amount");
      GameControls.Create(hWnd, 10, 375, 100, 40, "Game Controls");
      PlayerLabels.Create(hWnd, 10, 10, 100, 20, "You:");
      PlayerLabels.Create(hWnd, 10, 175, 100, 20, "Dealer:");
      HandValueLabel.Create(hWnd, (int)You.x[You.cards] + 85, 60, 100, 20, Buffer);
      YourMoney.Create(hWnd, 125, 500, 100, 40, "Your money: ");
      sprintf(Buffer, "%d", You.money);
      MoneyValue.Create(hWnd, 125, 525, 100, 40, Buffer);
      //Create buttons
      Ok.Create(hWnd, 10, 600, 100, 50, "Ok");
      Hit.Create(hWnd, 10, 425, 100, 50, "Hit");
      Stand.Create(hWnd, 120, 425, 100, 50, "Stand");
      //Select Text
      Bet.Select(0,3);
  }
  return 0;
  case WM_CLOSE:
    exit(0);
    break;
  case WM_COMMAND:
  {
      switch(HIWORD(wParam))
      {
      case BN_CLICKED:
      {
          switch(LOWORD(wParam))
          {
          case ID_OK:
          {
              //Place bet
              int bet = 0;
              bet = StringToNumber(Bet.Text());
              game.SendMessage(hWnd, ID_OK, START_GAME, bet, "");
          }
          break;
          case ID_HIT:
          {
              //Tell the game that the player wants another card
              game.SendMessage(hWnd, ID_HIT, HIT, 0, "");
          }
          break;
          case ID_STAND:
              game.SendMessage(hWnd, ID_STAND, STAND, 0, "");
          }
      }
      break;
      }
    }
  break;
    default:
    //Default:
    game.SendMessage(hWnd, 0, IDLE, 0, "");
    return DefWindowProcA(hWnd, Msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
  return 0;
}
```